# How to build a community around a private project?

Tags: small-communities, privacy, experienced-members

I am planning a web application and have actually gotten started on it on my own, and I am now trying to reach out to people so I can find others who'd like to contribute or join the project. After asking a few friends their thoughts on where I should ask for help, they all said GitHub, which I understand since it does have a strong way of getting users to want to contribute to others' projects. However, that is mostly, if not all, for open-source projects, while I'm trying to keep mine private and later proprietary (someday). Where and how should I mention my need for help without losing too much info or getting the attention of too many people?

Comment: Why would others be interested in contributing to your project, in particular if it's not open source?

Comment: It definitely is questionable, but it would be toward an application that would eventually and hopefully start profiting @gerrit